# Discord buttons all triggering at once. Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am attempting to create moderation on my discord bot that flags words as inappropriate and then allows the moderation team to easily ban/timeout the user without having to be present during the event. All of the moderation works, but only if I run the code once. If there are multiple button sets, they all trigger at once when one of them is pressed. For example, if I have press the ban button on one message, it will ban all users that have spoken inappropriately, rather than just banning the one person.

How do I fix this?

EDIT: I managed to fix the problem that all my button are pressed at once, and have run into a new button. Now, when one button is pressed, the rest of them fail if pressed. It's clear the code is resolving all instances of button_cxt, but I'm not sure how to prevent that or work around it.

Updated Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_profanity(message, word):

    try:
        guildID = message.guild.id
        guild = bot.get_guild(guildID)
        channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name="moderation-logs")
        channel_id = channel.id
    except:
        return None

    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id) 
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Profanity Alert!", description=f"{message.author.name} just said ||{message.content}||. The bad word was: ||{word}||", color=discord.Color.blurple()) # Let's make an embed!
    await channel.send(embed=embed)

    buttons = [
            manage_components.create_button(
                style=ButtonStyle.red,
                label="Ban!",
                custom_id="ban"
            ),
            manage_components.create_button(
                style=ButtonStyle.gray,
                label="Give them a Warning",
                custom_id="warning"
            ),
            manage_components.create_button(
                style=ButtonStyle.green,
                label="Nope!",
                custom_id="noBan"
            ),
          ]

    ActionRow = manage_components.create_actionrow(*buttons)

    if "warning" in [y.name.lower() for y in message.author.roles]:
        botMessage = await channel.send("They have already been warned. Do you wish to ban them?", components=[ActionRow])
    else:
        botMessage = await channel.send("Do you wish to ban them?", components=[ActionRow])


    button_ctx: ComponentContext = await manage_components.wait_for_component(bot, components=ActionRow)
    origin_id = button_ctx.origin_message.id

    if (botMessage.id == origin_id):
        await botMessage.delete()
        if button_ctx.custom_id == "ban":    
            await channel.send("The deed has been done.")
            bot.dispatch('ban', message, guild)

        elif button_ctx.custom_id == "warning":
            await channel.send("The warning has been sent!")
            bot.dispatch('warning', message, guild, channel)

        elif button_ctx.custom_id == "noBan":
            await channel.send("No action taken")
```

Answer (score 0):

so it took me a long time, and some thinking, but I did finally solve the problem. The issue was with these two sections:

```
button_ctx: ComponentContext = await manage_components.wait_for_component(bot, components=ActionRow)
```

The button context is listening for any buttons with the components ActionRow, which is all of the components for all of my buttons. Therefore, all buttons trigger their instance of the function at once. My small check means that only the one pressed does it's action, but it didn't stop the rest of the buttons from triggering that event listener.

So, the fix I thought of is to recursively restart all of the listeners if they aren't pressed. Do the action of the button pressed, and restart the function for the rest. Therefore, my now functioning code looks like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_profanity(message, word):

    try:
        guildID = message.guild.id
        guild = bot.get_guild(guildID)
        channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name="moderation-logs")
        channel_id = channel.id
    except:
        return None

    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id) 
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Profanity Alert!", description=f"{message.author.name} just said ||{message.content}||. The bad word was: ||{word}||", color=discord.Color.blurple())
    await channel.send(embed=embed)

    buttons = [
        manage_components.create_button(
            style=ButtonStyle.red,
            label="Ban!",
            custom_id="ban"
            ),
        manage_components.create_button(
            style=ButtonStyle.gray,
            label="Give them a Warning",
            custom_id="warning"
            ),
        manage_components.create_button(
            style=ButtonStyle.green,
            label="Nope!",
            custom_id="noBan"
            ),
          ]

    ActionRow = manage_components.create_actionrow(*buttons)

    if "warning" in [y.name.lower() for y in message.author.roles]:
        botMessage = await channel.send("They have already been warned. Do you wish to ban them?", components=[ActionRow])
    else:
        botMessage = await channel.send("Do you wish to ban them?", components=[ActionRow])

    await modButtons(guild, message, channel, botMessage, ActionRow)



async def modButtons(guild, message, channel, botMessage, ActionRow):

    button_ctx: ComponentContext = await manage_components.wait_for_component(bot, components=ActionRow)
    origin_id = button_ctx.origin_message.id

    if (botMessage.id == origin_id):
        await botMessage.delete()
        if button_ctx.custom_id == "ban":    
            #await channel.send("The deed has been done.")
            bot.dispatch('ban', message, guild)

        elif button_ctx.custom_id == "warning":
            #await channel.send("The warning has been sent!")
            bot.dispatch('warning', message, guild, channel)

        elif button_ctx.custom_id == "noBan":
            await channel.send(f"No action taken for {message.author.name}")

    else:
        await modButtons(guild, message, channel, botMessage, ActionRow) #recursion HERE!
```